# How to make hyperlink in asp .net grid view

Tags: c#, gridview, hyperlink

I have a table in SQL Server with column `X,Y,Z` 
which I have retrieved in gridview in ASP.Net.

Now I want the first field (example; X) to be a hyperlink as I click to open a new page. How can I do that with the code ?.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [HyperLinkField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx) to the gridview and set its DataNavigateUrlFields property to "X" and the Target property to "_blank".

Answer (score 0):

```
<Columns>
<!-- first column-->
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Details.aspx?Id={0}&Name={1}&Country={2}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Id").ToString()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Name").ToString()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Country").ToString())) %>'
            Text="View Details" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


<!-- second column-->
<asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />       

<!-- third column-->
<asp:BoundField DataField="Town" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" /> 

<!-- fourth column as hyperlink -->
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" /> 
</Columns>
```